# Is there an easier way to allow all http methods in Sanic framework?

Tags: python, http, sanic

I'm developing a proxy server by using Sanic. (The reason why I chose this framework is that it is so fast and it uses asynchronous event loop.)

So I want to catch all requests to my Sanic server and do some post-processings.

```
@app.route("/<path:path>", methods = []) # Here is the question point
async def proxy(request: Request, path: str):
   // do something
  return redirect("...")
```

I think it is not so good to write all HTTP methods and pass them through `methods` parameter. So I want to know if there is a more effective way to allow all HTTP methods to my route.

Thanks in advance.

- Python version: 3.11
- Sanic version: 23.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Answering my own question

I just have to get all values of the enum `HTTPMethod`. I don't understand that I didn't come up with such an easy solution.

```
@app.route("/<path:path>", methods = list(map(str, HTTPMethod)))
async def proxy(request: Request, path: str):
   // do something
  return redirect("...")
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you need it but here are [Sanic docs. Routing](https://sanic.dev/en/guide/basics/routing.html#routing) that will explain to you more in detail. In short, Sanic will automatically allow all non-safe HTTP methods for the route if you omit `methods`

Comment: Well... I know that Sanic allow only GET requests if I omit `methods`. When I request other HTTP method to the route which omits `methods`, it returns 405 error. I already did it myself.

Comment: interesting in docs here [Router.add in v19.9.0](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/v19.9.0/sanic/api_reference.html?highlight=route#sanic.router.Router.add) it tells that if you omit `methods` then any method is allowed. But here [HTTP request types in v20.12.3](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/v20.12.3/sanic/routing.html#http-request-types) says that it'll allow only `GET`